# Column name changed in to UPPER value and not recognized as valid column name in snowpark?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to filter a table with a column and certain value in snowpark. But query excution fails says that the given column name not identified in the table as it recognize column as UPPER value

```
snow_session.table("economy.data_atlas").filter(col("Country") == "United Arab Emirates")
```

Here the column name in the table is 'Country' , but the error shows that

```
invalid identifier 'COUNTRY'.
snowflake.connector.cursor: query: [SELECT  *  FROM economy.data_atlas WHERE ("COUNTRY" = 'United Arab Emirates')]
```

wondering why the column name become a case sensitive which looks very strange. i checked the query with 'Country' in the worksheet, which return the result

Any help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this dataset the column has a case-sensitive name: "Country". You can check it using the command: `desc table economy.data_atlas;` In order to use this column you should use the name exactly how it is written surrounded by double-quotes. It will disable the default case capitalization. See the [doc reference.](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax)

Therefore, as you've known, the correct syntax in SQL will be like:

```
SELECT * FROM economy.data_atlas WHERE ("Country" = 'United Arab Emirates');
```

The same will not work in Python as it will omit the double quotes for its own syntax purposes. Therefore you should add another pair of quotes to ensure that the name of the column is double quoted. Try this:

```python
snow_session.table("economy.data_atlas").filter(col('"Country"') == "United Arab Emirates")
```